# sIBL_GUI has stopped working

Tags: light

So I installed sIBL on Windows 10 and for some reason I keep getting sIBL_GUI has stopped working after trying to add a template under the Export tab, Blender Cycles Standard. The file browser will pop up, and after about 2 or 3 seconds, it errors and closes.

I've reinstalled numerous times, shut down AV/Firewalls, cleaned the living crap out of the computer, to no avail. Tried compatibility mode, ended as many processes as I could, but I just could not figure out what the heck was going on.

Then I pulled out my laptop, and the same exact thing happens. I'm not sure what's going on! Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm brand new to blender, but was walked through by someone to do this, and he wasn't sure what was going on either.

Comment: So is this a question about Blender or sIBL?

Comment: sIBL I suppose. I figured someone who uses sIBL with blender would know, since that's what I'm trying to do. When I searched for sIBL issues, this is the stack exchange that came up. Figured it was fitting.

Comment: Well my guess is your question will eventually get closed for being [off topic](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), since this is a Blender specific site. Well for what is worth have used in the past some of their HDR images but never used the software, so I can't really help there. You may have to contact the developer, or I'd suggest trying their [community site](http://www.hdrlabs.com/cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.pl) instead

Comment: So you are asking about the standalone program, not the blender addon?

Comment: I was speaking about sIBL which I am using with the blender add-on, however it was happening in the GUI of sIBL itself. Opening the file dialog would crash the program for me. I did find my solution which is below. it's just using a previous version, which fits my needs, though is probably not ideal for some.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found my answer. This isnt really a good answer, but it did solve my issue.

I thought maybe this could provide some useful insight to some people, or possibly the creator.

I tested every version of sIBL from 4.0.8 (latest) all the way down to 4.0.2.

4.0.2 does not crash upon opening a file dialog, however everything above this version crashes for me.